# Pulling out one discriminated union case in F#?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Suppose I have a DU like:

```
type Fruit = 
| Apple of string * bool
| Banana of string
| Cherry of string
```

Then I have a collection like this:

```
fruits : Fruit list
```

I want to pull out all of the `Apple` instances to perform some computation:

```
// apples is Seq<string * bool> 
let apples = 
  fruits
  |> Seq.choose (fun x -> 
    match x with 
    | Apple a -> Some a
    | _ -> None
  )
```

My question is: **is there a more concise way to write this?**

Something like:

```
// Not real code
let apples = 
  fruits
  |> Seq.match Apple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not much really. This is as concise as you can get:

```
let apples = 
  fruits
  |> Seq.choose (function Apple(a,b) -> Some(a,b) |_-> None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more concise is possible; you don't have to use Seq.choose:

```
let apples = fruits |> List.filter (fun fruit -> match fruit with Apple _ -> true | _ -> false)
```

If you need this in more places, extract the lambda into a helper function

```
let isApple = function | Apple _ -> true | _ -> false
```

Comment: This does not give a list of `Apple` (if I am not mistaken!)

Comment: List.filter takes a predicate and a list, and gives you a list

Comment: I want a `string * bool` list